# Replacing the values in a column with the frequency of occurence in same column in excel/sql/pandas

Tags: python, mysql, excel, pandas

I am having a table which contains over 600000 records and a column named implementer_userid, value in which may get repeated for more than one record. Now i want to store how many times a particular distinct value is occuring in that column. COUNTIF(Excel), GroupBy(sql) and similar functions wont work as i dont want a count of a specific value and instead replace all distinct values with their frequencies. Help me by doing so in any one of the three frameworks: **Excel, Pandas(Python) & SQL**.

[image]

Comment: Create pivot table in Excel and count the result which you need.

Comment: So in the above screenshot, would you replace 6509 by 3? At the moment I don't see why countif or group by couldn't do this(in excel it would be countif (B$2:B,b2) copied down through all the rows and in sql I think you'd need a join).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can just construct a frequency table using value_counts() function, and then go through your column, replacing keys (row values) with the respective frequencies, as retrieved from the dictionary you've constructed earlier. For example:

```
frequencies = your_pandas_dataframe['Your column'].value_counts()
your_pandas_dataframe['Result column'] = your_pandas_dataframe['Your column'].apply(lambda x: frequencies[x])
```

If you don't want this extra column, you can probably do something like this instead:

```
# ...
your_pandas_dataframe['Your column'] = your_pandas_dataframe['Your column'].apply(lambda x: frequencies[x])
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: now what if i wanted to count the frequency of a column based on condition in other column. For above example lets say i want to replace implemented_userid with number of times it appeared in table when it's corresponding tr_reference column had value=1.

Comment: I suppose that could first filter your dataframe by tf_reference (only keeping the records where tf_reference is 1), and then apply value_counts() on that filtered data. Then use your new value counts with a similar data.apply(func) construct.

Comment: So, something like:
df_filtered = df[df['tf_reference'] == 1]

counts = df_filtered['implemented_userid'].value_counts()
implementer_userid_frequencies_column = df_filtered['implemented_userid'].apply(lambda x: counts[x])
P.S: the end of line formatting for the comments is a bit strange. This is supposed to be 3 lines of code.

Comment: Ok this does half of the job but the problem with above code is that it doesnt replace those key's values whose tr_reference was 0 since we are applying our funciton only on df_filtered. Applying instead on df['IMPLEMENTED_USERID'] could have done it but it shows key error as a lot of keys are not present in the count. Any suggestions forward?

Comment: So what i am saying is let's say you have 20 rows where userid=4280. Now 12 of them have tr_reference=1, hence value in counts for this key(4280) becomes 12. Now when we apply our function it changes the value of only those 12 rows where tr_reference was 1. Instead i wanted to replace all 20 rows with value=12

Comment: I guess that in this case instead of using the function lambda x: counts[x], you need to replace counts[x] with a conditional expression, which you can put into another function. For example:
def apply_freq_table(k, d):
    if k not in d.keys():
        return 0
    else:
        return d[k]
And then your lambda becomes lambda x: apply_freq_table(x, counts)